# textarea is filled with [object HTMLMetaElement] in IE 10

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, internet-explorer-10

I am using Underscore.js in to render the html page.

```
this.template = _.template($(templateName).html());
```

I am having textarea in my html page like this.

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" rows="4"><%= typeof description == 'undefined' ? '' : description %></textarea>
```

In Underscore.js its going to the below line to replace the desription content.

```
if (interpolate) {
    source += "'+\n((__t=(" + interpolate + "))==null?'':__t)+\n'";
}
```

Now, the problem is for textarea it returns the result like this..

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" rows="4">'+
((__t=( typeof description == 'undefined' ? '' : description ))==null?'':__t)+
'</textarea>
```

As for checking the empty value for textarea, we cant use null, we have to use ' '. So Its not going to if condition, it throws the else value '__t'

The other broeswers accept it and display nothing inside the textarea. But IE 10 shows the content `'[object HTMLMetaElement]'` inside the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for this.

I have added one more condition for fixing it.

Replaced this line

```
source += "'+\n((__t=(" + interpolate + "))==null?'':__t)+\n'";
```

with this line in underscore.js

```
source += "'+\n((__t=(" + interpolate + "))==null?'':((typeof __t == 'object' && JSON.stringify(__t) == '{}') ? '': __t))+\n'";
```